# Unit testing the tower of hanoi problem

Tags: unit-testing, towers-of-hanoi

If I was unit testing the tower of hanoi problem, what would be the best cases? I can test the parameters and the general expected output of the method, but is it possible to test anything else?

So I could test: Output is correct (algorithm has worked), arguments are of the correct assumption (ie not null), anythine else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, the Hanoi problem is solved so quickly i almost think you could test any input vs the correct output in an acceptable time.